# How to get unmatching records using self join

Tags: mysql, self-join

So let's say I have a table called `users` with the following columns :

```
 user_id (int), 
 job_id (int),
 created (date)
```

I want to grab two users and get unmatching records based on `job_id`.

Example

```
user_id  | job_id | created 

15242    |  234   | 2015-04-07 
15242    |  441   | 2015-04-08
15242    |  345   | 2015-04-08
24521    |  234   | 2015-04-09
```

I want to get job_ids 441 and 345.

So a self join is required

```
SELECT users.job_id
FROM users as switch_from
LEFT JOIN users as switch_to ON switch_from .job_id = switch_to .job_id
WHERE switch_from.user_id = 15242 AND switch_to.user_id = 24521;
```

Shouldn't this give me all the job_ids from aliased table `switch_from` missing from aliased table `switch_to` ?

This returns the only row with matching job_id.

Comment: What are "unmatching rows"? What do you mean by "job id is missing"?

Comment: Btw, `LEFT JOIN x ... WHERE x.y = <something not null>` in fact turns the outer join into an inner join.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT switch_from.job_id
FROM users as switch_from
LEFT JOIN users as switch_to ON switch_from.job_id = switch_to.job_id AND switch_to.user_id = 24521
WHERE switch_from.user_id = 15242 AND switch_to.user_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could also use the minus statement:

```
SELECT member_id, name FROM a
MINUS
SELECT member_id, name FROM b
```

If you want the records from switch_to that are nog in switch_from, it can be done like this.

```
SELECT users.job_id FROM users as switch_to
WHERE switch_to.user_id = 24521
MINUS
SELECT users.job_id FROM users as switch_from
WHERE switch_from.user_id = 15242;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT users.job_id FROM users as switch_from
   LEFT JOIN users as switch_to ON 
   ( switch_from .job_id = switch_to .job_id and switch_to.user_id = 24521 )
   WHERE switch_from.user_id = 15242
```